# Find max and min of $11\cos^2\theta+3\sin\theta+6\sin\theta\cos\theta+5$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, maxima-minima

I'm trying to solve the following question from my textbook.

> Using the identity $\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1$ and $a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos(\theta-c)$, where $c$ is a constant, find the maximum and minimum values of $$11\cos^2\theta+3\sin\theta+6\sin\theta\cos\theta+5$$

$$\begin{align}
11\cos^2\theta+3\sin\theta+6\sin\theta\cos\theta+5 &=5.5(\cos2\theta+1)+3\sin\theta+3\sin2\theta+5 \\
&=5.5\cos2\theta+3\sin2\theta+3\sin\theta+10.5 \\
&=\sqrt{39.25}\cos(2\theta+28.610°)+3\sin\theta+10.5
\end{align}$$

And now I'm kind of stuck. Did I approach the question wrongly?

Comment: The identity $acos(\theta) + bsin(\theta) = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}cos(\theta-a)$ is not correct.

Comment: Where did you get the value $c=-28.610$ it seems to me $c$ should be $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @JustinStevenson Well, we need $\cos c=\frac{11}{\sqrt{157}}$, so $c$ is $0.499346722$ in radians or $28.6104596843^\circ$.

Comment: Please double-check the given problem.